# A problem During running OracleDBConsoleoracle service

Tags: oracle

I am facing this problem when I try to run OracleDBConsoleoracle in oracle 11

"Windows could not start the OracleDBConsoleoracle on Local Computer.For more information, 
review the System Event Log.If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to
service-specific error code 2."

Noteice:I was online when I  installed Oracle 11.

What's the problem?
Thanks...

Comment: Was there anything in the event logs (system or application)?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to answer this we might need a little more info. What exactly did you install? What database did you create? Did you create the database and configure DBConsole on it? When did it work OK (if at all)? When did it stop working for you? Is you database and listener still running? What changed?

maybe [Oracle® Database Quick Installation Guide
11g Release 1 (11.1) for Microsoft Windows (32-Bit)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/install.111/b32301/toc.htm) can be of any help?

[Ronald](http://ronr.blogspot.com)